# Passing cx_oracle error code

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm performing inserts in 4 different tables using cx_oracle and need to pass the return_Val, error.code and error.message.

```
func1 
  try:
     insert1()
     insert2()
     insert3()
     insert4()
     return_val = True
  except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, ex:
     return_val = False
     print error.code
     print error.message

  return return_val, error.code, error.message
```

When the inserts are successful, I get the following error message,

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'error' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Well, `error` is unbound, you might want to replace it by `ex` …

Answer (score 0):

You need to include as the first line in the exception handler:

```
error, = ex.args
```